# How can I use getopts in a script that appends lines from files in a separate directory to a new file?

Tags: bash, getopts

I am trying to write a bash script that takes in a directory, reads each file in the directory, and then appends the first line of each file in that directory to a new file. When I hard-code the variables in my script, it works fine.

This works:

```
#!/bin/bash

rm /local/SomePath/multigene.firstline.btab
touch /local/SomePath/multigene.firstline.btab

btabdir=/local/SomePath/test/*
outfile=/local/SomePath/multigene.firstline.btab

for f in $btabdir
do
    head -1 $f >> $outfile
done
```

This does not work:

```
#!/bin/bash

while getopts ":d:o:" opt; do
  case ${opt} in
    d) btabdir=$OPTARG;;
    o) outfile=$OPTARG;;
  esac
done

rm $outfile
touch $outfile

for f in $btabdir
do
    head -1 $f >> $outfile
done
```

Here is how I call the script:

```
bash /local/SomePath/Scripts/btab.besthits.wBp-q_wBm-r.sh -d /local/SomePath/test/* -o /local/SomePath/out.test/multigene.firstline.btab
```

And here is what I get when I run it:

```
rm: missing operand
Try 'rm --help' for more information.
touch: missing file operand
Try 'touch --help' for more information.
/local/SomePath/Scripts/btab.besthits.wBp-q_wBm-r.sh: line 23: $outfile: ambiguous redirect
```

Any suggestions? I'd like to be able to use `getopts` so I can make the script more generic. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have to pay extra attention to [quoting](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes#Prevent_field_splitting_and_ignore_glob_pattern_characters) and [globbing](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/globbingref.html) when writing bash scripts.

When you call the script with a glob (`*` here) it gets expanded and split into words by your shell. This happends before your script even gets executed.

If you for example do `cat *.txt` cat will get all .txt files in the directory as its arguments. It will be the same as calling `cat afile.txt nextfile.txt` (and so on). Cat will never see the asterisk.

In your script it means that the input `-d /local/SomePath/test/*` gets expanded som something like `/local/SomePath/test/someFile /local/SomePath/test/someOtherFile /test/someThirdFile`.
Subsequently `getopts` only takes the first file after `-d` as for `$btabdir` and the `-o` doesn't get handled in the case switch.

I suggest you start by quoting every variable, preferable in the `"${name}"` style, and only invoke the script with quoted input. 
It might also be send in a directory path, test that it is a directory (`test -d`),  and change your for loop to `for f in "${btabdir}"/*`

Answer (score 0):

This also works:

```
head -n1 -q /local/SomePath/test/* >> /local/SomePath/out.test/multigene.firstline.btab
```

Comment: Yes that is probably the easiest way, it's not bash though.

Answer (score 0):

I think the right answer here is "don't do it that way." :-)

The reason your current script isn't working may be that the wildcard is expanded by your interactive shell, not by your script. Try running your command with an `echo` at the beginning of the line for a hint at what's really happening. Once `getopts` sees the second of the matched files in the glob, it stops processing options, so `-o` never gets read, and `$outfile` remains unset. And since you don't quote your variable in `rm $outfile`, it's as if you're running `rm` without options. Test the difference in your shell between `rm` alone and `rm ""`.

Also, what happens to your `for` loop if there's a space in a filename? Since you have bash, you have arrays. And arrays are *much* better for processing lists of files.

Perhaps use something like this instead:

```
#!/bin/bash

# initialize an array
files=()

while getopts :d:o: opt; do
  case "$opt" in
    d)
      if [[ ! -d "$OPTARG" ]]; then
        printf 'ERROR: not a directory: %s\n' "$OPTARG" >&2
        exit 65
      fi
      # add to the array
      files+=( "$OPTARG"/* )
      ;;
    o) outfile="$OPTARG" ;;
    *)
      printf 'ERROR: unknown option: %s\n' "$opt" >&2
      exit 64
      ;;
  esac
done

if ! rm -f "$outfile" && touch "$outfile"; then
  printf 'ERROR: cannot create %s\n' "$outfile" >&2
  exit 73
fi

for f in "${files[@]}"; do
  read -r < "$f"
  printf '%s\n' "$REPLY"
done > "$outfile"
```

Here are some highlights of the changes....

- We're using arrays, of course. The array `${files[@]}` will contain one-file-per-record, without relying on whitespace, so with proper quoting you'll avoid problems with special characters in filenames.
- We test for more error conditions, and actually show errors and exit if we see them. (The exit values are [sysexits](http://man.freebsd.org/sysexits).)
- Instead of using `head`, we use `read` and a single redirect to `$outfile`. This saves multiple forks to an external program, and multiple `fopen()` calls to your output file.

Note that the argument to `-d` should be a *directory*, not a glob. And you can specify options multiple times. Multiple `-d` options will be added together, but only the last `-o` option will be used.